# Mongo "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$filter'"

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute following query in latest mongo 3.4.1 server and the 3.4.1 shell.

```
db.dealer.aggregate(
[
{$match:{salesAreaId:{$in:[ObjectId("5858d03ec5109a098c854802")]}}},
{$lookup:{
    from:"outstanding",
    localField:"_id",
    foreignField:"dealer_id",
    as:"outstandings"
    }},
 {$filter:{
     input:"$outstandings",
     as:"outstandings",
     cond:{
         $is:{"$$outstandings.finalized":false}
         }
     }}
]
)
```

But it says

```
Error: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$filter'",
"code" : 40324,
"codeName" : "Location40324"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) `$filter` is supporting from v3.2 onward.
Any help.

Comment: $filter should be wrapped in $project pipeline stage

Comment: Thanks. it is correct

Answer (score 3):

Replace the below code

```js
db.dealer.aggregate(
[
{$match:{salesAreaId:{$in:[ObjectId("5858d03ec5109a098c854802")]}}},
{$lookup:{
    from:"outstanding",
    localField:"_id",
    foreignField:"dealer_id",
    as:"outstandings"
    }},
 {$project:{
     outstandings:{$filter:{
     input:"$outstandings",
     as:"outstandings",
     cond:{
         $is:{"$$outstandings.finalized":false}
         }
     }
     }
     }
 }
])
```

Comment: when I do this I get: `MongoError: invalid operator '$is'`